# RadWindow UI Issue

Tags: css, asp.net, telerik

So I added a `RadWindow` to my `aspx` page

`file1.aspx` (points to cssfile1.css)

Within that aspx file, there's a `RadWindow` which opens a `RadWindow` that contains another `aspx` file

`file2.aspx` (points to cssfile2.css)

My question is, how do I override the `CSS` in `file2.aspx` that seems to be messing with the `RadWindow`. And if it is the `CSS` in file1.aspx, how do I omit the `CSS` for this `RadWindow`?

[image: RadWindow Issue]

Answer (score 0):

It is the main file (cssfile1.css from page1.aspx). The second pair are loaded in an iframe so they don't affect the topmost frame.

To resolve the problem, there are three approaches:

- **try the Lightweight RenderMode** as it uses more semantic HTML so it may not get affected (i.e., it is not a table): http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/mobile-support/render-modes.
- Do a binary **search in the stylesheet to find the offending rule and make it specific enough** so it does not target all HTML elements. Basically, follow this article: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/troubleshooting/distorted-appearance
- use the browser dev toolbar to **find the elements in the RadWindow that are affected by your rules and add a heavier CSS selector that will reset them** (e.g., remove paddings you add, whatever).